# Get content from iFrame, where is the error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, iframe

I'd like to get the security zone (Internet zone / local intranet) for a number of URL's which are in the same domain. I thought the best solution would be to get this through iFrame. 
@Teemu. Code works now. Thank you very much. But one problem so far: It displays the wrong text. Although the page is in trusted zone (local intranet) he displays "untrusted" (Internet zone). Any idea why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">


function getZone() {
    var text = new Array();
    document.getElementsByClass('iframeNames');

var test;
for (var i = 0; i < document.frames.length; i++) {
try {
    test = document.frame[i].contentWindow.document;
    text[i] = "Trusted (Local Intranet)";
} catch (e) {
    text[i] =  "Untrusted (Internet Zone)";
}
} //end-for

    var showText = getElementsByClass("zone");
    for (var i = 0; i < showText.length; i++) {
        setText(showText[i], text[i]);
    };
} //end getZone()

function setText(showText, text) {
    showText.innerHTML = text;
} //end setText

if (document.getElementsByClassName) {
    getElementsByClass = function (classList, node) {
        return (node || document).getElementsByClassName(classList);
    };
}

</script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.format {
    background-color: #ffff;}

#formatierung {
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 30px;
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 13px;

}

</style>

<body>

<iframe src = "http://example.com" class = "iframeNames" width = "0" 
height ="0"></iframe>
<iframe src = "http://example.com/index/" class = "iframeNames" width = "0" 
height =  "0"></iframe>

<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

getZone();

};
</script>


<div id = "formatierung">

<table width = "100%">


<tr class = "format"><td><h2>System</h2></td><td><h2>Check Security-Zone</h2></td></tr>
<tr><td>example1</td><td class = "zone"></td></tr>
<tr><td>example2</td><td class = "zone"></td></tr>

</table>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What do you need this for in the first place? (I'm baffled this is possible at all)

Comment: This line: `value[i] = frames[i].isTrustedIE()`. `frames[]` is a collection of the "window" objects in the document. These members of the collection don't have a property named `isTrustedIE()`, so your script will throw an exception.

Comment: I don't get any result of the security zone, so he doesn't display any text (trusted / untrusted). This first for should iterate the iFrames. With the command frames[i].isTrustedIE() should check the security zone of the current URL. I don't know if this command is right, at this statement I was unsure ;).

Comment: @Teemu. Could you give me an alternative to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var test;
for (var i = 0; i < document.frames.length; i++) {
    try {
        test = document.frames[i].document;
        text[i] = "Trusted (Local Intranet)";
    } catch (e) {
        text[i] =  "Untrusted (Internet Zone)";
    }
}
```

With this code you won't need `isTrustedIE()` at all.

Like I said in my previous comment, `frames[]` is a collection of the "window" objects in the document. This code just checks, if it can get a reference to the `document` in the `iframe`. It's not possible, when `iframe`'s content is loaded from cross-origin source.

Comment: But where do I call the function isTrustedIE()? And what does this mean: document.frames[n].document?

Comment: @user1860908 I've edited my answer. I suppose you can use a nodelist produced by your own `getElementsByClass()` function instead of `document.frames[]`. In that case `frame[i].document` might return `undefined` also from intranet frames, hence use `frame[i].contentWindow.document` instead.

Comment: I've edited the abovementioned code with your part, but unfortunately it didn't display the required result! :(.

Comment: @user1860908 There's a typo in your code... `frame[i]` should be `document.frames[i]` : ).

Comment: Code works now. Thank you very much. But one problem so far: It displays the wrong text. Although the page is in trusted zone (local intranet) he displays "untrusted" (Internet zone). Any idea, why???

Comment: @user1860908 That's why it took a while before I posted the code. There seems to be something strange in IE's frames collection. Only way I got it to work, is the original code in my answer (ie. using `frames[i].document`, not `frames[i].contentWindow` which seems to be `undefined` within `frames` collection.) BTW there's still a typo in your post (`frame[i] !== frames[i]`) : ).

Comment: It's a strange thing, but it works now :). Thank you very very much for your help!